# Is is possible to downgrade the Netmiko version from 3.0.0 to 2.4.2

Tags: netmiko

I ran into some issues after upgrading to Netmiko's latest version 3.

Is it possible to downgrade the Netmiko version from 3.0.0 to 2.4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by doing below -
1) pip3 unsintall netmiko
2) pip3 install netmiko==2.4.2
Thanks

Comment: You might also want to create a GitHub issue on the Netmiko repository for your issue (so I can fix them for Netmiko 3.x.x going forward). Thanks.

Comment: @Kirk Byers- Sure I was about to do that.